# Director not directing senior managers, should we confront them?

Tags: management, communication, work-experience

I currently work for a firm which has a director and six senior managers, including me.  The managers have all discussed how they feel the company is not being led correctly.

We feel the director hasn't got enough business experience and is also a very poor communicator.

The main issue though, is the fact that there is no strategy in place and no one knows where the company is heading.  Should we confront the director in a general management meeting and voice our concerns?

We're unsure whether as senior managers, we should be coming up with ideas on how to steer the company forward (which we are), but with this, we're unsure on which direction we're steering into.

Comment: **should we confront them**? what do you mean here?  What do you hope to achieve.  Should you do it or not is asking for opinions.  How do I achieve X we can help with .

Answer (score 3):

Six managers got together to discuss how poor of a communicator your boss is and couldn't figure-out how to voice your concerns?

It would be great if every boss just put the goals on a big poster, but usually those are a waste. Notice they never say "We want to be the third-best company and only occassionally meet customer's expectations when they're willing to pay exhorbitant fees."

**Just Ask** - Is it really that hard? It takes two sides to have communication.

**Listen** - Hard to believe you've had no conversations, email, directives or anything from this person. Does she have to spell it out for you? If your supervisor sends out 3 reminder emails to get the fax cover sheet on the TPS Reports, guess what the goal is?

**It's Obvious** - Make more money! Do you really want the person without business experience telling you how to do it? You have free-reign. No accusations of micro-manageement here. Stop waiting to be told what to do. For a group of self-proclaimed experienced business people with great communcations skills, you don't act like you've done this before. You're managers, take charge. Can't wait to see the posts from your subordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "yes". Given that you believ that it hurts the business without this change, you should confront the director.

I am not sure if it is a good idea to do it during a general management meeting. It sounds like some sort of all out attack that could make the director very defensive, but if you know that (s)he is most likely to listen, go ahead and do it.

As manager (generally, any employee), you are there to help the business to stay sustainable and support it to grow. Doing so not only helps the business and its shareholders, it'll come back to you as well.

If you believe that the director needs support to support you in one way or another (in order to help the business grow as per above), make sure that you voice this concern before it is too late.

Just remember that getting to the point where an actual solution is in place can be a long journey, and you'll probably need the support of the director all the way, so do everything possible to get him or her to buy into your suggested change as early as possible.